What DVD image should I choose to write on a DVD
Well, somehow standard desktop 24.04 amd64- .iso image is 6 GiB, not 4,7GiB that can be burnt on a standard DVD disc (and not all BIOSes allow to boot from USB sticks). Why is that?
And how can I burn it if it doesn't fit? Where can I get the right .iso image to burn Live and Installation DVD?
Why there's no option that will fit in and that is on a surface?

Is there a reason you can not use a dual layer DVD? You tag 22.04 and say 24.04 in the question which is correct?

DVDs come in different types, the dual layer is 8.4GB and the cheaper single layer is 4.77GB; so if you want to use a DVD; purchase & use a dual layer DVD.   FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD refers to the dual layer capacity as 8.5GB

"Why is that?" Because most folks migrated many years ago to using a USB stick instead of a DVD. And because the existing software tends to grow in size as new features are added. And because many folks keep asking for more and more software to be included in the installer.

Can Ubuntu live session boot from a dual layer DVD?

You have to either use a USB stick, or use a different flavor of Ubuntu.
Almost all Ubuntu flavors are less than 4.7 GB, except (the regular) Ubuntu.
Alternatively, you can also install Ubuntu Server (2.7 GB) with a DVD. It has a command line interface. Run the following command to install the default Ubuntu Desktop interface after installing Ubuntu server.
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

